# How can i copy strings which are palindrome from one file to another using python

Tags: python-3.x

I already wrote the code but i could not find any strings which are palindrome in another file.

```
    f=open("strings.txt","w") 
    n=int(input("Enter number of strings "))
    print("Enter strings")
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        str=input()
        f.write(str)
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()
    f=open("strings.txt","r")
    f1=open("palindrome.txt","w")
    f1.write("Palindrome strings are")
    for e in f:
        if e==e[::-1]:
            f1.write(e)
            
    f.close()        
    f1.close()
```

Comment: `str` is the name of the string type in python and you have used it as a variable name, this will cause all sorts of issues. You will need to `.strip()` the strings to remove newlines to find any palindromes. Also look into the `with` statement for safer handling of the files.

Answer (score 1):

```
f=open("strings.txt","w")
n=int(input("Enter number of strings you want to enter"))
print("Enter strings")
for i in range(1,n+1):
    v=input()
    f.write(v)
    f.write("\n")
f.close()
f1=open("palindrome.txt","w")
with open("strings.txt","r") as f:
    f1.write("Palindrome strings are\n")
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            if word==word[::-1]:
                f1.write(word)
                f1.write("\n")                
f1.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, the problem is that there are no palindromes.

Suppose your input was 2 strings
aa,aba

When you store them, you are storing them as aa\naba\n

When you run the loop,

```
for e in f:
```

e takes the values aa\n, aba\n
Now you are checking for palindrom-ness of aa\n and aba\n, which they are obviously not because of the added \n

So, just do e.strip(), to reomve the new line